# How can I find all functions that have no access level specified?

Tags: ios, swift, static-analysis

We have a big quantity of functions in legacy-code that have no access level specified, so they all fall back into the default access level, "**Internal**".
I would like to make them all "**Private**" and see if there are any build errors, so that I can quickly tell if some of them should be converted to Private.
I can't find a quick way of doing that.
Does anyone know of a tool or a trick for that? Maybe a shell script or a linter with this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following **Regular Expression**. It matchs all lines that starts with `func`.

```
^\s*func
```

- `^` matches start of line
- `\s*` matches any number of space. *You may have different levels of indentation.*

[image]

#### update

You can use or (`|`) operator to match `@objc` and `mutating`.

```
^\s*func|@objc|mutating
```

---

#### Info:

You may not need to change the access modifiers in `SceneDelegate` and `AppDelegate`. If so, click on `In Project` and then choose the following search scope.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Looks good. Will require some easy variations because of @objc, mutating and maybe some other prefixes. I will try it out and will mark this as an accepted answer as soon as I see that it works.

Comment: @ArikSegal You are welcome. Check the update.